# Auto fit a non activex userform shapes and boxes to different screen sizes?

Tags: excel, vba

- **Challenge**
  Userform pictures/shapes and textboxes does not fit to different screen sizes.
  I have different users with different desktop/laptop screen sizes
- **Misconception**
  I don't want to fit userform itself, I just want to fit objects(combobox/pictures) instead.
- **What I have tried**
  I tried to convert it to an active x form (to fix the shapes regardless of the screen size) instead but it would take a long time to rename shapes and re-write the code. (Not time efficent)

  - I tried to fix the width, top, height, disable/enable auto fit for all objects as well as userform, but still don't fit.
  - I tried to recognize the screen size and then fit objects, not time efficient

I need to fit shapes inside a non active x userform to fit all screen sizes, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It worked only when I converted the USERFORM (Code & Design) to ActiveX Form (Worksheet).

Only thing to change from (ME.Object Name) to (Thisworkbook.worksheets("Name").ObjectName)

It took some time but worked finally.